# Find first value in a vector of concatenated running sequences

Tags: matlab

Given a vector like

```
[1;2;3;5;6;7;10;11;12]
```

which is an ordered subset of `transpose(1:N)` for some `N`, how do I find the first value in each running sequence? Here, running sequence are sequences of integers separated by 1, e.g. `5;6;7`. From the above vector I expect the answer to be:

```
[1;5;10]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/).

```
a = [1;2;3;5;6;7;10;11;12]
a([true; diff(a)>1])        %% or a(diff([-inf; a])>1)
ans =

     1
     5
    10
```

`diff(a)` will give you the difference between all elements. `diff(a)>1` will return a logical vector indicating which of the numbers had a difference more than `1`.

`[true; diff(a)>1]` will append a single logical true in the start, to make sure the first value is included.

Finally `a([true; diff(a)>1])` will give you the values of `a` that are mapped by the logical vector.